# Why I'm getting "PreflightDisallowedRedirect" when fetching URL on ReactJS untill I add a trailing slash, and only for this URL?

Tags: php, reactjs, .htaccess

I'm working on a React App, that fetchs data from api wrote with php. The api folder's structure is like this:

```
api/
  |
  |---.htaccess
  |---news/
  |    |
  |    |---news.php
  |---tenders/
       |
       |---tenders.php
```

The .htaccess file was created to "beautify" the fetching urls

```
RewriteRule ^news/?$ news/news.php
RewriteRule ^tenders/?$ tenders/tenders.php
```

As you can see, both rewriting rules are written in the same way.

When fetching **tenders** api on development environment, it works well, but, does not work when fetching **news**.

React fetching Code:

```js
        return fetch('https://website.tld/api/news', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
        return fetch('https://website.tld/api/tenders', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
```

Again, the URL are written the same way, but I receive the following error only for **news** URL

> Access to fetch at 'https://website.tld/api/news' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

But, I noticed that the fetching works when adding a trailing slash:

```
https://website.tld/api/news/
```

I don't understand why I have to add the trailing slash only for this URL. In other side, the **news** api works on production **without** trailing slash.

Comment: Your problem likely has to do with the [`DirectorySlash`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) directive.

Comment: I read the documentation, it can be the cause. Thank you.